# Binding Map<String, HashMap<String, String>> instance from text box in HTML

Tags: java, model-view-controller, groovy, playframework

I am working in play framework with groovy script in front end. I want to map value in text box to `Map<String, HashMap<String, String>>` instance in corresponding model object. I have used following code for that. But they are not working.

Html code is given below

```
    #{form @ControllerApp.review(), method:"POST"}
        <input class="new-party-address" type="hidden" value="Customer name: Pramil Address Line 1: NA " name="p.parties[added_1].strdaddress">
        <input class="new-party-address" type="hidden" value="Pramil" name="p.parties[added_1].address">
   <input type="Submit"/>
    #{/form}
```

Model object is given below

```
public class PartyInput {
  public Map<String, HashMap<String, String>> parties = new HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>>();
}
```

Controller is given below

```
    public class ControllerApp extends Controller {
    public static void review(PartyInput p) {
    System.out.print(p); //null
    }
}
```

Routes file is given below

```
POST    /Controller/review     ControllerApp.review
```

Java code is given below

```
public Map<String, HashMap<String, String>> parties = new HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>>();
```

But I got parties as null in java object. I want hashmpap structure as `{added_1={address="Customer name: Pramil Address Line 1: NA", strdaddress="Pramil"}}`. What I have to do for that

Comment: attach error trace please

Comment: There is no error. Binding is not working

Comment: Extend your html to scope at least the form, also with the java code please